# Get the full retweeted tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy and Python to access the Twitter API.

I would like to know if the following problem is common or it's happening just for me.

I am storing some tweets.
Retweeted ones are stored in this fortmat:

```
RT @User [text of the tweet]
```

I notice here that even a user retweeted the text using the "Retweet" button, the text is always stored in the same format (`RT @User [text of the tweet]`) and of course when the Twitter API adds "`RT @user`" the whole text can exceeds 140 character and as a result it is stored but not in its full length.

If the problem is not a common bug, for those who used Tweepy, does the bug comes from it or from Twitter API ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy Truncated Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050289/tweepy-truncated-status)

Answer (score 5):

Retweets are special kinds of tweets with an additional node called "`retweeted_status`".
The original, unaltered tweet text of the original tweet is in the text field of retweeted_status, not the top-most text field like traditional tweets.

Try following,

```
import tweepy
import urllib2
import json
consumer_key='#'
consumer_secret='#'
access_token_key='#'
access_token_secret='#'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="@HandleHere",count=25,page=1,include_rts=True)
all_items=[]
[all_items.append(i) for i in public_tweets]

for i in all_items:
    try:
        if i.retweeted_status:
            print i.retweeted_status.text
    except:
        pass
```

It will print full retweeted tweet.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but a normal behavior. To quote [the tweeter documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) for the truncated field:

> Indicates whether the value of the text parameter was truncated, for example, as a result of a retweet exceeding the 140 character Tweet length. Truncated text will end in ellipsis, like this ...
>
> [...]
>
> Note that while **native retweets may have their toplevel text property shortened**, the original text will be available under the retweeted_status object and the truncated parameter will be set to the value of the original status (in most cases, false).

Comment: It's wired since in Twitter the concerned tweet is not truncated but when reading it with the API it is truncated.