# How can I fetch the full text tweet from a truncated tweet id

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, status

I am trying to pull the data for a truncated tweet . There is a link at the end of the ellipsis.

I am using the tweepy library for fetching the data. The single status fetch gets the same tweet text as the truncated one.

Can anyone help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy Truncated Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050289/tweepy-truncated-status)