# Getting full tweet text from "user_timeline" with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy to fetch tweets from a user's timeline using the script included [here](https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496). However, the tweets are coming in truncated:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200, full_text=True)
```

Returns:

```
Status(contributors=None, 
     truncated=True, 
     text=u"#Hungary's new bill allows the detention of asylum seekers 
          &amp; push backs to #Serbia. We've seen push backs before so\u2026 https:// 
          t.co/iDswEs3qYR", 
          is_quote_status=False, 
          ...
```

That is, for some `i`, `new_tweets[i].text.encode("utf-8")` appears like

```
#Hungary's new bill allows the detention of asylum seekers &amp; 
push backs to #Serbia. We've seen push backs before so…https://t.co/
iDswEs3qYR
```

Where the `...` in the latter replaces text that would normally be displayed on Twitter.

Does anyone know how I can override `truncated=True` to get the full text on my request?

Comment: what are you doing to receive that return?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, just saw this - I am just pretty-printing `new_tweets[0]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tweepy Truncated Status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050289/tweepy-truncated-status)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Instead of full_text=True you need tweet_mode="extended"

Then, instead of text you should use full_text to get the full tweet    text.

Your code should look like:

```
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200, tweet_mode="extended")
```

Then in order to get the full tweets text:

`tweets = [[tweet.full_text] for tweet in new_tweets]`

Comment: It is not working in my case. I'm still getting truncated tweets. :(

Answer (score 13):

Manolis's answer is good but not complete.  To get the extended version of a tweet (as in Manoli's version), you would do :

```
tweetL = api.user_timeline(screen_name='sdrumm', tweet_mode="extended")
tweetL[8].full_text
'Statement of the day at #WholeChildSummit2019 - “‘SOME’ is not a number, and ‘SOON’ is not a time!” IMO, this is why educational systems get stuck. Who in your system will initiate change? TODAY! #HSEFutureReady'
```

However, if this tweet is a retweet, you'll want to use the retweets' full text:

```
tweetL = api.user_timeline(id=2271808427, tweet_mode="extended")
# This is still truncated
tweetL[6].full_text
'RT @blawson_lcsw: So proud of these amazing @HSESchools students who presented their ideas on how to help their peers manage stress in mean…'
# Use retweeted_status to get the actual full text
tweetL[6].retweeted_status.full_text
'So proud of these amazing @HSESchools students who presented their ideas on how to help their peers manage stress in meaningful ways! Thanks @HSEPrincipal for giving us your time!'
```

This was tested with `Python 3.6` and `tweepy-3.6.0`.

Comment: I was looking exactly for this. Thanks !

Comment: how can I ensure if the given status is a tweet or a retweet? Edit: nevermind, I found a way of doing so. Thanks for this answer :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I now get the Twitter user's full text in their tweets from their timeline.