# twitter tweet_mode = 'extended' not just giving me the text in the tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to download tweets using tweepy. But the tweets keep getting cut off.

```
results = api.search(q=hashtag, lang="en", count=num, tweet_mode="extended")
for tweet in results:
    tweet_list.append(tweet.full_text)
```

I end up getting outputs looking like this:

> RT @Acosta: Trump also said at the meeting “why do we need more Haitians? Take them out,” a person familiar with today’s meeting confirms t…

I just want the actual full text part of the tweet.

Comment: Check the full_text field on the Tweet object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705314/getting-full-tweet-text-from-user-timeline-with-tweepy)

> Instead of full_text=True you need tweet_mode="extended"
>
> Then, instead of text you should use full_text to get the full tweet text.
>
> Your code should look like:
>
> new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200, tweet_mode="extended")
> Then in order to get the full tweets text:
>
> tweets = [[tweet.full_text] for tweet in new_tweets]

Comment: I did this and now I'm not getting the full tweet I'm getting the ... at the end

Comment: Sorry I was able to fix it myself the issue was involving retweets