# how to get the full status text from twitter API with JSON?

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, tweepy

**tldr: how to access the FULL tweet body with JSON?**

Hello

I have a problem finding the full text of a tweet in JSON.

I am making a python app with tweepy. I would like to take a status, and then access the text

**EDIT**

I used [`user_timeline()`](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) to get a `tweet_list`. Then got one tweet from them like this:

```
tweet=tweet_list[index]._json
```

now when I do this:

```
tweet['text']
```

it returns a shortened tweet with a link to the original

eg:

> Unemployment for Black Americans is the lowest ever recorded. Trump
>   approval ratings with Black Americans has doubl…
>   (the shortened link, couldn't directly link due to stackoverflow rules)

I want to return this:

> Unemployment for Black Americans is the lowest ever recorded. Trump
>   approval ratings with Black Americans has doubled. Thank you, and it
>   will get even (much) better! @FoxNews

I don't mind if the link is added as long as the full tweet is shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay after looking a bit more. I believe it is impossible to do it directly with JSON

There is a solution here about getting the full tweet. you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42705314/getting-full-tweet-text-from-user-timeline-with-tweepy)

The problem with the answer above is that `full_text` turn the object into a string. if you need the object in its initial state to use it later with json to get other info. do the following:

1. use  `tweet_mode="extended"` in  `user_timeline()` and save it in `tweet_list`. eg:

`tweet_list = api.user_timeline("user", count=10, tweet_mode="extended")`

2. take one tweet only like this: `tweet=tweet_list[0]`
3. if you want the full text tweet, do this: `tweet.full_text`
4. if you need a json version of the object do this `jtweet = tweet._json` or just access the key like this `tweet._json['id']`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any information about, how you want to achieve your goal. Looking at tweepy API, there is optional flag argument full_text which you can pass to function. [get direct message function](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.get_direct_message)

It defaults to false causing that returned messages are shortened to 140 chars. Just set it at True and see what happen.

Comment: Can you describe how to access tweet's full text within a cURL query? There is an error in cURL query: "Unknown parameter 'tweet_mode' ".